# React es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6

What does this syntax mean?

this part : *$FlowFixMeProps, $FlowFixMeState*

```
class Tester extends React.Component<$FlowFixMeProps, $FlowFixMeState> {
...
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: That is Flow syntax for generic parameters to the `React.Component` class.

Comment: Where is the code from? A comment like _//$FlowFixme/_ will suppress a complaint from Flow resulting from code in the following line, but we wouldn't normally write code with props & state named like $FlowFixMeProps etc. Flow 0.53 first introduced the need for specifying your component's Props and State types (see changelog). It looks like this code was generated by a codemod and you should replace these with actual types: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/41b0eab99cdc5199421f7cccad9e0c4950f8b2f9/packages/flow-upgrade/src/upgrades/0.53.0/ReactComponentExplicitTypeArgs/codemod.js

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's from the type checking library FlowJS.

See: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Comment: It's not a "type checking library", it's a preprocessor language for strictly typed JavaScript.

Comment: Got it ;) , PropTypes approach with a "short syntax" for props and by including PropTypes for state.

Comment: @EatsIndigo I did. Not once does it label Flow as a "library".

Answer (score -1):

This syntax looks like typescript to me.

The $FlowFixMeProps is the class of your react component's props and $FlowFixMeState is the class of your react component's the state.

An example of using typescript with react is [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-why-a-guide-to-using-typescript-with-react-fffb76c61614).
You can maybe find more information of how this react/ts combination can work.